# More fluent cooperation of FileServe and Routing

Tags: angularjs, go, router, gorilla

I have an issue where I want to serve my main AngularJS (Yeoman deployment) app folder on FileServe `/` but it will destroy all my router bindings. Is there any way I can reserve them and keep my routes in-tact?

In the code below I still have to go to `/app` and re-bind the other folders, because I don't want to temper with the Grunt file too much (yet), so added some extra backup path-bindings for the folders.

```
func initializeRoutes() {
    // Handle all requests by serving a file of the same name
    fileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir(*clFlagStaticDirectory))
    bowerFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../bower_components"))
    imagesFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../app/images"))
    scriptsFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../app/scripts"))
    stylesFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../app/styles"))
    viewsFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../app/views"))

    // Setup routes
    mainRoute := mux.NewRouter()
    mainRoute.StrictSlash(true)
    // mainRoute.Handle("/", http.RedirectHandler("/static/", 302))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/app").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/app", fileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/app/bower_components").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/bower_components", bowerFileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/bower_components").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/bower_components", bowerFileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/images").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/images", imagesFileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/scripts").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/scripts", scriptsFileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/styles").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/styles", stylesFileHandler))
    mainRoute.PathPrefix("/views").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/views", viewsFileHandler))

    // Basic routes
    // User routes
    userRoute := mainRoute.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()
    userRoute.Handle("/login", handler(userDoLogin)).Methods("POST")
    userRoute.Handle("/logout", handler(userDoLogout)).Methods("GET")
    userRoute.Handle("/forgot_password", handler(forgotPassword)).Methods("POST")

    // Bind API Routes
    apiRoute := mainRoute.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()

    apiProductModelRoute := apiRoute.PathPrefix("/productmodels").Subrouter()
    apiProductModelRoute.Handle("/", handler(listProductModels)).Methods("GET")
    apiProductModelRoute.Handle("/{id}", handler(getProductModel)).Methods("GET")

    // Bind generic route
    http.Handle("/", mainRoute)
}
```

So my goal is the serve `/app` as my `/` main path, but reserve all my Mux Routes to win over the FileServe. So if I'll have a `/app/users/login` folder, it won't load, but instead it will let the Router win.

Note: I'm serving purely over `HTTPS` and nothing over `HTTP`.

Thanks so much in advance! This is breaking my brain and it's the last thing I need to figure out before I can fully start on my front-end code :).

Comment: I'd consider using `httprouter`, it's more flexible. I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve here and why the duplicate routes.

Comment: You didn't read my question at all. Your comment is a typical demotivating response.. I've explained exactly what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: I tried reading your code and really couldn't figure out what's going on. Perhaps you can simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks for me like you want to change the order of how the routes are evaluated in a way that `/users`, `/login`, and similar are matched before the `/`. And the `/` should be server by the FileServer.

As far as I know, the routes will be matched in the order they are defined (added to the router). So you just have to move your API and other dynamic routes before `/`.

The following code works similar:

- the `/test` match is evaluated before the file server and returns the string "OK"
- then the file server returns the file under the path

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    appFileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/Users/alex/Projects/tmp/so/app"))
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/test").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("OK"))
    })
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(appFileHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```